# How to create class with only one instance in C++

Tags: c++, class

Is there any way to allow only one instance of a class in C++?
If there is, please expain to me. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean `static` you can make the constructor private, and have a method `newInstance()` that returns only one instance

Comment: Try the singleton pattern.

Comment: @Dan: Near, but no banana.

Answer (score 6):

This is the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). You can achieve this via a public static attribute and a private constructor:

```
class Singleton {
    public:
        static Singleton * const singleton;
    private:
        Singleton(void) {}
};
Singleton * const Singleton::singleton = new Singleton();
```

**Edit:** Good point from Dan Watkins; If you really want to be draconian about it, you can disallow copy and assignment by also explicitly declaring those methods private:

```
    private:
        Singleton(void) {}
        Singleton(Singleton& other) {}
        Singleton& operator=(Singleton& other) {}
```

Comment: Copy and assignment though... Otherwise I can do this: Singleton a = *Singleton::singleton; Singleton b = a;

Comment: Too complicated. And no way to clean it up. Also, it can be copied. Consider a `public static` function returning a reference to a `static` instance (advantage: Construction on demand), or just a `public static` member. And don't forget to disable copying.

Comment: @Deduplicator what you mentioned (a.k.a. Meyers singleton) is also guaranteed to be thread safe in C++11, so this is the way to go if you really need singletons. The most elegant way I found is to implement it via a CRTP in which you derived from `Singleton<Base>` and make `Singleton<Base>` friend in `Base`. Then all singleton functionality (deleting copying etc) can be made in `Singleton<T>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, you can always add a public static method to allow destructing the singleton instance.

Comment: And when should it be called? Better let the compiler do it automagically at the appropriate time.