# How to create single instance of base class

Tags: c++, constructor, singleton

I have a class GenericRoot which has a number of classes that descend from it. I would like to create only a single instance of this class. I am familiar with this approach which I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338175/how-to-create-class-with-only-one-instance-in-c):

```
    class genericRoot {
    private:
        genericRoot() {}

    public:
        static genericRoot &getInstance ();
    };

class Handler : public genericRoot {
}
```

However, this results in every Handler (and every other class that descends from Generic Root) to get two errors:

> "error: within this context"
>
> "error: genericRoot::genericRoot is private"

Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Sure. Make the default constructor of `genericRoot` a `protected` member function.

```
class genericRoot {
  protected:
    genericRoot() {}

  public:
    static genericRoot &getInstance ();
};
```

Having said that, I want to warn you that the need for an object of the base class does not sound right. It's a symptom of a design flaw somewhere. Think about your requirements a bit carefully and figure out whether there is any way to meet the requirements without creating an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, no.  The point of making the `genericRoot` constructor private is to prevent instances of it being created anywhere but in the `getInstance` factory method.  When you create an instance of a `genericRoot` subclass, you implicitly create an instance of `genericRoot` too.  (In fact, the new object *is* a `genericRoot` while the `genericRoot` constructor is running.)

So the design needs a bit of a rethink.  I presume the idea here is to have all subclasses share some common state.  If this is the case, then perhaps some private static state would make more sense than the singleton pattern.  Something like:

```
class genericRoot
{
private:
  static SomeType private_state_;
protected:
  // whatever state accessors are needed for subclasses...
};
```

In lieu of a constructor for `genericRoot`, you would simply initialize the private state inside the corresponding `cpp` file:

```
SomeType genericRoot::private_state_ = InitializePrivateState();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to construct a subclass of `genericRoot` while keeping `genericRoot`'s constructor private, you can declare each subclass to be a `friend`, as so:

```
class genericRoot {
private:
    genericRoot() {}
    friend class Handler;

public:
    static genericRoot &getInstance();
};

class Handler : public genericRoot {
};
```

I do, however, agree with the other answers that you should think carefully about why/whether you really need subclasses of a singleton class, as it is quite an odd situation.